# cuando cerrar la conexion a la base de datos?

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, nodejs

a lo que me refiero con el titulo es lo siguiente, yo he estado haciendo pequeñas pruebas con mysql en nodejs. pero luego queriendo hacer una pequeña pagina de registro e inicio de sesión surgió esta duda: luego de conectar el servidor a la base de datos debería dejar la conexión abierta para reutilizarla o cerrarla y volverla a conectar cuando necesita una petición.

Comment: En los modelos actuales, se usa cerrar la conexion una vez que la usaste. Los pool de conexiones hacen que los tiempos de apertura y cerrado sean superfluos. Mantener la conexion abierta implicaria que si 100000 usuarios se conectaran a tu pagina.. y solo se sentaran a mirarla, tendrias 100000 conexiones abiertas...

Comment: vaya muchas gracias eso no lo sabia

Comment: y porfa mira el [tour] y tambien [ask]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si estás realizando una conexión y consultas a través de una función, lo recomendable es cerrar conexión justo antes de cerrar la función, si la función sera llamada nuevamente la conexión se volverá a abrir y no existe problema alguno.